# performSelectorInBackground makes memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

This gives me memory leak, even thought I call create and release pool in the selector function.

```
[read_qr performSelectorInBackground:@selector(newThreadWrapper) withObject:nil];
```

class read_qr:

```
 - (void) newThreadWrapper {
         reading = YES;
         NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
         [self another_function:arg];             
         [pool release];
         reading = NO;

    }
```

There is no leak if I call the same function in the main thread without performSelectorInBackground.

Any tips are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You usually `drain` NSAutoreleasePool instead of `release`. That should not result in a leak, though. The code you posted is fine.

Comment: How do you detect the leak? Instruments? Static code analyser?

Comment: I tryed drain, but still gives me a leak.
I am detecting a leak with instruments. Could the instruments bee the problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: Static code analyser gives me no leak warning. Should that comfort me? :)